# How can i create a javascript object array containing a date value and image. The requirement is as follows:

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Requirements**

1. Expecting the following format:

   `var news = [{caption: STRING_VALUE, post_time: DATE_VALUE, description: STRING_VALUE, image: IMAGE},....];`
2. This should be placed as a dummy data in the server side. (ie, not on database, but if it successfull i need to implement this using Mondodb and node.js. Currently am working with Node.js only, following MVC)
3. Use this dummy data into the webpage inside an li tag as follows: (Am using the ejs as view engine)

   `<ul>
   <% for (var i=0;i<news.length;i++){ %>
   <li><%=news[i].description+" -- "+news[i].post_time%></li>
   <%}%>
   </ul>`

Comment: You need some way of passing data between the client and the server.  Can you give us a little more context about how/what type of data this is so that we can suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since data has to communicated over a network we do not send the datevalue object or an image object directly in the data. Instead send the images relative path and rely on the browser to render it and pass a datetime string and later parse it in the js.

Assuming you'll be saving the images on the server for now with a relative path /images. You can configure your server endpoint to return a javascript array!(JSON array) as

```
[
    {
        "caption": "This is Image 1",
        "post_time": "2017-10-12",
        "description": "This is Image 1 description",
        "image":"/images/image1.png"
    },
    {
        "caption": "This is Image 2",
        "post_time": "2017-10-13",
        "description": "This is Image 2 description",
        "image":"/images/image2.png"
    }
]
```

In *ejs* you will be able to use the *img* tag to display the image.

```
<ul>
<% for (var i=0;i<news.length;i++){ %>
<li>
    <img src="<%= news[i].image %>" alt="">
    <%=news[i].description+" -- "+news[i].post_time%>
</li>
<%}%>
</ul>
```